# Search does not find a specific tag, but it is present

Tags: support, tags

Last week I created the tag [successor-arithmetics](/questions/tagged/successor-arithmetics) and tagged several questions with it. Now, I can no longer search for such articles: The [tag search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/successor-arithmetics) says 0 questions tagged.

However, if I search [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D%20%22s%280%29%22), many of the tagged articles show up - together with the tag.

Edit: When I am connected anonymously on another machine I can see the 11 questions.  But as false, I don't.  And: I do not have ignored tags...

Edit: Solved.  I should have look at the result in more detail.  However, the actual reason for this misunderstanding is the following:

As long, as I search for a single tag, I get the riders "info", "newest", "faq", "votes", "active", "unanswered".

But when I search for a tag plus a searchstring, I get the riders "relevance", "newest", "votes", "active".

So when I cross-checked, I got "better" results, because I now got the "relevance" rider in place of the "faq" rider.

Comment: @Lix see above comment to Mat :)

Comment: @Sha - thanks :) Pop into the Tavern when you have some time :P

Comment: @Lix only if you pay for the drink! :)

Comment: @sha - fine :P Be like that... see you durring the happy hour :P

Answer (score 5):

Ok, problem solved.  This was the reason: whenever I clicked on [successor-arithmetics](/questions/tagged/successor-arithmetics), or searched for it in the search box, I got the FAQ tab - which says 0 hits...  I did not realized that this hidden state was present everywhere...

Comment: Your last chosen tab is selected by default.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: I *did* know this very well.  It is only that when you add an additional searchstring - you get these "better" results which made me blind on this